# Is this last name Jurglič?

Tags: palaeography, vital-records, austria, german-language

I have this last name written a bunch of times (underlined in red):

From a Status Animarium in early 1800s, the first instance is written to end in `zh` which I believe is German way to write `č`
[image]

Here is second from Status Animarium in mid 1800s:
[image]

And the third from 1837 marriage record where the surname occurs twice:
[image]

Are these four underlined writings of surname all referring to the surname Jurglič?

Comment: Yes, there is such a surname like "Jurglic" or "Jurgliĉ". I don't understach your question's purpose.

Comment: @GeorgeGaál for such a question your comment may suffice as an answer.

Comment: @GeorgeGaál Are these four writings of surname all referring to the surname Jurglič?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, all these underlined writings refer to the surname "Jurglič".

In these times the priests wrote what they heard and everyone heard it differently and so there are several different forms of names in the church books.